# combine all posible conditions in PHP

Tags: php, artificial-intelligence

In my application I need to get best value
the application code like:

```
function funcA($data, $index) {
    if ($data[$index]['a'] > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function funcB($data, $index) {
    if ($data[$index]['b'] > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function funcC($data, $index) {
    if ($data[$index]['c'] > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

$data=array(
array('a'=>1,'b'=>-7,'c'=>32,'val'=>5),
array('a'=>12,'b'=>24,'c'=>-2,'val'=>-4),
array('a'=>3,'b'=>-4,'c'=>-3,'val'=>1));
```

I want to combine all possible conditions to get max value like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    if (funcA($data, $i) && funcC($data, $i))
        if ($data[$i]['val'] > $max) {
            $max = $data[$i]['val'];
            $condition = 'funcA&&funcC';
        }
    if ((funcA($data, $i) || funcB($data, $i)) && funcC($data, $i))
        if ($data[$i]['val'] > $max) {
            $max = $data[$i]['val'];
            $condition = '(funcA||funcB)&&funcC';
        }
}
```

How can combine all possible conditions?

Comment: Can you explain what you want in text

Comment: I want to find best formula to get max value.